# Prestashop export database and import it back

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to Prestashop and I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.17.

I want to export the database of my Prestashop site and back it up in order to make some modifications to the online database. However, I want to make sure that if something wrong happens I can import the just exported database and have it working again as before.

If so, should it work the same way as before exporting the database?

Besides, what if I made the database backup and then installed some modules that didn't work, or made some other back office modifications that went wrong, would the site work the same way as before after importing it back?

Just for general knowledge.

Comment: If it's just changes to the database then yes.

Comment: @PeterM ok, and what if I made the database backup and then installed some modules that didn't work, or made some other back office modifications that went wrong, would the site work the same way as before after importing it back?

Comment: As long as the modules don't overwrite any of the code outside the module it should be fine. Modules have to be enabled after being uploaded and that particular information is saved in the database. To be on the safe side I'd suggest to create a full backup though.

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop is comprised of a **database** and a **filesystem**. Backing up the database will allow you to recover from changes to the database, but not from changes to the filesystem. If you are going to use the "DB Backup" option under "ADVANCED PARAMETERS" bear in mind that a *live* shop may change while doing the backup, so it is better to do it while *offline*.

The restore operation will first drop all tables, so you have to make sure that your backup files are not corrupted *before* doing the backup.

The database is only half of it. A full backup will require to backup all the files. That may be done in many ways. The easiest one could be by setting the shop *offline* and then using an `ftp` client to copy all the files. This may be slow depending on the server and connection speed.

When you install a module, it will create a directory under `<prestashop root>/modules`. If the module is developed following standards, this directory will not clash with other core modules. However, a module installation may do lots of other things. It is always a good idea to **install modules from sources that you trust**. Also, a module is just a ZIP file that should have a single directory containing all its files. You may check the contents of the ZIP file to make sure.

A well developed module that behaves properly is easy to disable or uninstall. However, the installation scripts of the module (or uninstallation) may do any number of wrong things as well.

In general, **backup both the database and the filesystem** regularly and especially if you are going to try something with side effects. Installing a module may be one of those things, but modifying files here and there following instructions from someone's blog may be too. Changing a template usually involves changing `.tpl` files. Sometimes you may want to change `.css` files. Those changes have nothing to do with the database.